# Foreground service gets stopped after 1 minute (Android 12)

Tags: java, android, android-12

I'm trying to make a service that works 24/7 and it's been working until I updated to Android 12. I've checked the new foreground restrictions but still don't understand why it isn't working since I'm starting it from an activity.

ACTIVITY

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startForegroundService(new Intent(TestActivity.this, TestService.class));
    }
}
```

SERVICE

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.media.MediaBrowserServiceCompat;

import java.util.List;

public class TestService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {
    @Override
    public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String clientPackageName, int clientUid, @Nullable Bundle rootHints) { return null; }

    @Override
    public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull String parentId, @NonNull Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) { result.sendResult(null); }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent ii, int flags, int startId) {
        //CREATE NOTI CHANNEL
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    "test", "Test Notifications",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        //CREATE NOTI
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "test")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("test")
                .setChannelId("test")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSilent(true)
                .build();
        //START FOREGROUND
        startForeground(101, notification);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

I tried creating a new app with just these lines of code and it works fine so it must be something else making the service close after a minute.

Comment: How are you defining "gets stopped"? What are your actual symptoms? Does your behavior change if you extend `Service` instead of `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`?

Comment: With "gets stopped" I mean that it gets closed as if I did `stopSelf()`. About `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`, I tried changing it to `Service` and the same keeps happening. Also, in case someone asks I get no errors and I have `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permision in the manifest.

Comment: "I get no errors" -- there should be some messages in Logcat from the OS, not necessarily crashes. There always are when components get started and stopped.

Comment: The last message I get happens after exiting the app. When the service stops it does not log anything but in case I'm just not seeing the problem [here are the logs](https://jpst.it/2Xn0P)

EDIT: I open the app and then exit without closing it. After 1 exact minute the service stops and logs nothing.

Comment: Try removing `setSilent()` and otherwise simplify your `Notification`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out samsung put my app on deep sleep which caused it to close itself if not used for a minute. Also thanks to the people who took their time to try and help.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are correct in wanting a foreground Service here, it seems as if you want it to stay alive whenever you app in the background, or not running at all, as you don't intend your app to be running 24/7, do you?

Since it seems as if you're trying to use a `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` in your example, I would suggest you do so using a companion instance of a `MediaSessionCompat` in order to have the media session control the lifecycle of your Service on it's own.

Implementing a media Service is not the most straightforward task in Android; they're still trying to fix some of its prevailing issues with the latest release of Android 13.  Therefore, I would also suggest you follow [this official Android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app) if you're attempting to create an audio app with a media foreground Service.

Comment: Although I found the problem I'll actually check it out so thanks anyways